# getPlaceDetectionClient(android.app.Activity, com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacesOptions) is deprecated

Tags: android, google-places-api

Android Studio 3.1.4

```
placeDetectionClient = Places.getPlaceDetectionClient(this, null);
```

gave error:

```
getPlaceDetectionClient(android.app.Activity, com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacesOptions) is deprecated
```

Any idea use what instead? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Did you read the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Places.html#getPlaceDetectionClient(android.content.Context,%20com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacesOptions))?

`getPlaceDetectionClient(Context context, PlacesOptions options)` has been replaced with `getPlaceDetectionClient(Context context)`. Just remove the `null` parameter.

That's also not an error. It's a warning and is safe to ignore for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks, simple but effective.